# How to play any sound in kernel mode driver (Windows)

Tags: c++, c, windows, driver

I have a kernel driver and I need to play any sound by pressing the keyboard's key. This is what I have now, but can't figure out how to actually play the sound.

That's my University project and you can see my code below:

```
NTSTATUS ReadCompletionRoutine(IN PDEVICE_OBJECT pDeviceObject, IN PIRP theIrp, IN PVOID Context)
{
    PDEVICE_EXTENSION pdx = (PDEVICE_EXTENSION)pDeviceObject->DeviceExtension;
    PKEYBOARD_INPUT_DATA kidData;

    if (NT_SUCCESS(theIrp->IoStatus.Status))
    {
        kidData = (PKEYBOARD_INPUT_DATA)theIrp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer;
        int n = theIrp->IoStatus.Information / sizeof(KEYBOARD_INPUT_DATA);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            USHORT keyCode = kidData[i].MakeCode;

            switch (keyCode) {
                case 2: {
                    // Key "1" was pressed
                    DbgPrint("PLAY SOUND 1");
                    Sound();
                    break;
                }
                case 3: {
                    // Key "2" was pressed
                    DbgPrint("PLAY SOUND 2");
                    break;
                }
                case 4: {
                    // Key "3" was pressed
                    DbgPrint("PLAY SOUND 3");
                    break;
                }
                break;
            }

            //DbgPrint("Code: %x\n", keyCode);
        }
    }

    if (theIrp->PendingReturned) {
        IoMarkIrpPending(theIrp);
    }

    gnRequests--;
    /*__asm {
        lock dec gnRequests
    }*/
    return theIrp->IoStatus.Status;
}
```

Comment: What kind of sound do you want to play?  A sound file?  A Midi-generated sound?  There used to be HalMakeBeep(),(example available on GitHub)  but computers rarely come with a buzzer anymore.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy could you share example of this HalMakeBeep function?

Comment: It is on GitHub, google HaMakeBeep and you'll find it.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy hey, I found it, but seems its not working. My code:

UNICODE_STRING uFuncName;
     RtlInitUnicodeString(&uFuncName, L"HalMakeBeep");
     PULONG pHalMakeBeep = MmGetSystemRoutineAddress(&uFuncName);

     // Beep
     pHalMakeBeep(0x2000);

ERROR:
'pHalMakeBeep': not a function

Comment: Like I said: computers don't come with a buzzer anymore.  HalMakeBeep() relies on the presence of a buzzer.  Buzzers were popular in the days when sound cards were not.  That's quite a while ago.  And....  Don't you EVER check function return code?  That's a no-no when writing kernel code.  Always check return codes and handle errors/generate log entry.  AND a PULONG is not a function pointer, is it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.